# Parsing timestamp with Python2.4

Tags: python, datetime, parsing, python-2.4

I want to parse a timestamp from a log file that has been written via

`datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')`

and then compute the number of seconds that have passed since this timestamp.

I know I could do it with `datetime.datetime.strptime` to get back a `datetime` object and then compute a timedelta. Problem is, the `strptime` function has been introduced with Python 2.5 and I'm using Python2.4.4 (an upgrade is not possible in my context).

Any easy way to do this?

Comment: you should change the title as some people may find this to be offensive.  Also I did downvote you for that very reason.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: That's ok. Changed it even before I read your comment.

Comment: now I'm curious what the original title was :P

Comment: @wayne: edit history is available.

Comment: lol ... it said "retarded Python" instead of "Python2.4" which might have made people think I despised this awesome language

Comment: @Chris: ah, I see now, thanks! @jelybean: Or some people also like to take offense at calling things retard(ed).

Comment: dito. I don't think someone will answer this question.

Comment: I meant to use "retarded" in the meaning of "staying far behind current development". It's probably not the p.c. term to use ... if you really need to downvote me because I used it to refer to a _programming language version_ in a _former_ title of my question, please go ahead. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> ts = time.mktime(time.strptime('20040412234551', '%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))
>>> ts
1081809951.0
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts)
datetime.datetime(2004, 4, 12, 23, 45, 51)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
then = datetime.datetime(*time.strptime('20080227034510' ,'%Y%m%d%H%M%S')[0:6])
difference = now - then
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`strptime`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4.4/lib/module-time.html#l2h-1957) function in the `time` module in python 2.4 already. You'd have to convert that to a datetime object for example via the detour of the unix timestamp, don't know if there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

There's also mx.DateTime which is now free to use and it quite a bit easier to deal with and more flexible than Python's built in datetime module for well just about everything.  Works in python 2.3+  No * and [0:6] shenanigans required.

[Egenix Download](http://www.egenix.com/products/python/mxBase/)

```
>>> import mx.DateTime as dt
>>> then = dt.DateTimeFrom(dt.strptime('20040412234551', '%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))
>>> delta = dt.now() - then
>>> delta
<DateTimeDelta object for '2247:13:09:22.31' at 2ab37d666b58>
>>> delta.hours
53941.156198977762
>>> delta.days
2247.5481749574069
```